# Conditions for a finite Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Under what circumstances is the Fourier series of a function guaranteed to have a finite number of coefficients?

Comment: When the function you want to represent is a finite sum of $\sin$ and $\cos$? What conditions are you looking for?

Comment: Indeed, as Jonas says, on the face of it the answer is simply that this happens if and only if the function is a **trigonometric polynomial**, i.e., a polynomial in sine and cosine.  Are you looking for something deeper than this?  If so, what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it is annihilated by a constant-coefficient differential operator! :)

Not hard to prove, I think, under the assumption that you have a periodic function.

Edit: a "constant coefficient" differential operator is of the form $c_n{d^n\over dx^n}+c_{n-1}{d^{n-1}\over dx^{n-1}} + \ldots + c_1{d\over dx}+c_0$, where the coefficients $c_i$ are *constants*.

As an earlier comment noted, without the assumption of periodicity, in addition to exponentials and/or sines-and-cosines, also polynomial multiples of exponentials and sine/cosine are annihilated by suitable constant-coefficient differential operators. For example, $xe^x$ is annihilated by $({d\over dx}-1)^2$. Even more simply, $x^n$ is annihilated by ${d^n\over dx^n}$, after all. But under an assumption such as that $f(x)=\sum_k a_k\,e^{ikx}$, polynomial multiples are excluded.